# Mongo not inserting entire document on upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an object that looks contains:

```
listdate:'2023-09-12T04:05:12Z'
listid:'2959581028'
pr:60000
```

The listid is different from the mongo _id and is unique. I am scraping and trying to insert new records into a collection using:

```
  try {
        const filter = { "listing_id": obj.listing_id };

        // Update or insert document
        const update = {
            $set: {
                updatedAt: new Date(), // Set the updatedAt field to the current timestamp
            },
        };
        const options = { upsert: true };

        const result1 = await collection.updateOne(filter, update, options);
        counter = counter + 1;
        console.log('counter: ', counter);
        console.log('Upserted document:', result1.upsertedId || filter);
```

The already existing objects are updated with the updatedAt field, but the new objects look like:

```
id: 6500664973d73be34cbbf577
listingid:"2959581028"
updatedAt:2023-09-12T13:23:20.668+00:00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Depends what you expect from the upsert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you provided in the query:

- `listing_id`  from the filter
- `updatedAt` from the $set.

Both fields are in the upserted document + autogenerated _id.

If you want to add other fields, you need to provide them explicitly. Mongo cannot hallucinate yet.

My best guess is you want [$setOnInset](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) but it can equally be a filter or $set. Depends whether you want the rest of the fields updated on existing documents or not.

**Update**

for the "I would like upsert to insert the entire document if no match is found. " part of the comment, as I failed to comprehend the rest of it.

Assuming "the entire document" is

```
listdate:'2023-09-12T04:05:12Z'
listid:'2959581028'
pr:60000
```

the update statement should be:

```
const update = {
    $set: {
        updatedAt: new Date(), // Set the updatedAt field to the current timestamp
    },
    $setOnInssert: {    // Set fields for new documents only
        listdate:'2023-09-12T04:05:12Z',
        listid:'2959581028',
        pr:60000
    }
};
```

Comment: From the docs: `If no document matches the <query> parameter, the update operation inserts a document with only the replacement document.` So I think the `listing_id` should not be present in the new document.

Comment: My mistake, your answer is correct: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Em1tobR7LfD

Comment: I would like upsert to insert the entire document if no match is found. If a match is found I'd like to use the update document as above, to add or update only one field (updatedAt)

Comment: Thank you - you solved it. I guess I'm surprised that you need to go to so much trouble to insert the entire object by using the setOnInsert keyword. It seems intuitive to me to that the default should be to insert everything and that updating should be specified, because for the latter you may want to choose what to update ...

Comment: You still need to tell Mongo what "everything" is. $setOnInsert is exactly the place where you define this "everything" part. It's specific to your application, and even then you can have different "everythings" in different collections. Remember - it's a schemaless database. There are no "default" fields apart from _id.